# SharePoint 2013 Document Management

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

Does SharePoint 2013 have an OOTB function that removes documents from a specific library based on the time those documents have been stored in this library? Like if i have a document library, this function would look at the date when a document was added and deletes is if it has passed for example one month.

Thanks in advance
/Eliya Amanoeel

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163233.aspx

The CMIS producer supports basic document-management operations such as creating, updating, deleting, checking in and checking out, and managing the versions of documents and document metadata.

Comment: Sir, I really appreciate your reply, but the link doesn't provide sufficient information about my query.